# Use image instead of radio button

Tags: apex, visualforce, html

How can i use this code in Visualforce page with **apex:selectRadio**

```
  <label for="happy">
  <img style="cursor:pointer;" id="image1" height="50" width="50" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.smileys, 'happy_b.png')}" />
  <input style="Display: none;"  onclick="setVar(this.value, this.id); return true;"  id="happy" name="first" type="radio" value="Exceptional" />
</label>
```

I want to use something like this with VF page with **apex:selectRadio**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896156/how-do-i-style-radio-buttons-with-images-laughing-smiley-for-good-sad-smiley

Thanks